# file_get_contents and foreach loop - insert only the last record

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, file-get-contents

I'm writing script, which extract emails from the urls in the form and add them to the database.
I've got two problems:

1.Only the email from last url is added to the database.

2.How can I add an email to the database?;) When I use variable $email or $email[0] I receive in the table an empty field or Array. I have avoid this by using foreach loop, but I hope you'll find out some more convenient solution.

```
$linki = explode("\n", $_POST['linki']); 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'linki');  

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'error: ';
    exit;
}


foreach ( $linki as $link) {

    $przetwarzany_url = file_get_contents($link);

    preg_match( "/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $przetwarzany_url, $email);//email


    $query = "INSERT INTO urle set adres = '$email' "; //this query doens't add the email to db

    $result = $db->query($query);
    }
```

Here is my output from print_r($link); in the foreach loop:

```
firsturl.com array(0) { } secondurl.com array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "xxx@xxx.xxx" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got many points of failure:

1. You don't check if `$link` is valid - since it's coming from a web form, nothing stops a malicious user from entering things like 'http://childporn.com' and the like, which your script will then try to fetch the contents of.
2. You don't check if `file_get_contents()` actually returned anything
3. You don't check if the regex actually found an email address
4. You don't sanitize whatever DID match for insertion into the DB, so you've got an SQL injection hole
5. You don't check if the DB insert query actually succeeded

add checks to your code to handle all of these issues, and you'll probably find out why you're only get some inserts to succeed.

Comment: Ahh yes, childporn.com - I can't believe that got shut down, it was so inconspicuous... +1 for that alone, although the rest of your answer is +1able as well ;-)

Comment: Well, the .com naming rule is like Reddit Rule 34 - if it exists, there's a .com for it.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your answer. Actually i'm using this script on my localhost as you can see. Your checks are surely good, but the script will be used only by me and I've put it here in a such form to make it more clear. file_get_contents is not empty. Here is my output from print_r($link); in the foreach loop: http://firsturl.com array(0) { } http://secondurl.com array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "xxx@xxx.xxx"  }

Comment: Don't paste code blocks into comments. they get mangled... put that into your question above.

Comment: i've put it there. do you have some suggestions?

Comment: If that's $link, then you're trying to file_get_contents() an array, which doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure this? $linki is an array, but $link?

Comment: ok, i've done. Will post the answer in 5 hours, cause i don't have too much rep to post it now